# flutter_inAppWebView onLoadStart and shouldOverrideUrlLoading not called

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-inappwebview

I'm listening to both callbacks and both are only called occasionally.

I need a callback that is called every time a URL is changed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.